# CSS Not Input selector?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS rule:

```
.k-grid, .k-grid *   { border: 0 !important; }
```

But this applies to everything in the container, including `input` elements.

Is there a way to edit that CSS to add a "not" clause to exclude inputs? Everything else needs the border turned off.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this MDN article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not , it appears that you could do `.k-grid *:not(input)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have `:not(input)` selector in css to exclude the specific element.

```
.k-grid, .k-grid *:not(input)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes like this ...

```
.k-g >*:not(input){ border: none!important; }
```

examp.

http://jsfiddle.net/FJttr/